# Menu navigation with if and else in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

This is my little menu navigation with if and else statements:

```
def navigation():


    navigation_eingabe = int(input())


    if navigation_eingabe == 1:
        met1()
    if navigation_eingabe == 2:
        pass
    if navigation_eingabe == 3:
        pass
    if navigation_eingabe == 4:
        pass
    if navigation_eingabe == 5:
        pass
    if navigation_eingabe == 6:
        pass
    else:
        print("Pls give only Integer numbers")


def met1():
    print("method1")
    met2()

def met2():
    print("method2")


navigation()
```

Its not working correctly, after I give the Input as 1, the code goes to met1, then to meth2 and then to the else statement. I dont know why?

And then I program this alternativ code with a example:

```
def navigation ():
    x = int(input())

    if x == 1:
        print("1")
        xx1()
    if x == 2:
        print("2")
        xx2()
    else:
        print("else statement")


def xx1():
    print("this is met1")

def xx2():
    print("this is met2")


navigation()
```

But in this code, the statement is working correctly, why not in the first code? Is this a problem with functional programming logic, or with the statement structury? but I cant see the difference of this two codes.

Thank you!

Comment: This is a problem with the logic of this code: you should be using `elif` instead of multiple `if`s. Why? Step through your code with a pen and a piece of paper. Does the execution stop after any of the first 5 conditions are met?

Comment: Your last `if` does nothing if `navigation_eingabe` is `6` and prints a message in all other cases. `1` is not `6`, so it prints a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, when testing multiple conditions in the same block, you use `if` for the first condition, `elif` for other conditional statements after that, and then `else`. The code block under `else` runs only if the other conditions were `False`. The problem with your code is that you use all `if` statements where you should use `elif`. The reason your first code goes to the `else` statement is because your last `if` statement runs no matter what the result of the first `if` statement was.

```
if navigation_eingabe == 1:
    met1()
elif navigation_eingabe == 2:
    pass
```

put the rest of your `elif` statements, and end with the `else` statement, so it will print if none of the other conditions are true:

```
else:
    print('Pls only give integer numbers.')
```

However, this code does not do what you think it does. You are using the `else` statement for exception handling. This does not work. What you need is a `try-except` statement:

```
try:
    navigation_eingabe = int(input())
    if navigation_eingabe == 1:
        met1()
    elif navigation_eingabe == 2:
        pass
    elif navigation_eingabe == 3:
        pass
    elif navigation_eingabe == 4:
        pass
    elif navigation_eingabe == 5:
        pass
    elif navigation_eingabe == 6:
        pass
    else:
        print('not a number 1-6')
except ValueError: #the type of error if you try to convert a non-integer string to an int.
    print('Pls only give integer numbers.')
```

This will check each condition and catch the error if an invalid string is passed to the input.

Answer (score 1):

This happened because you thought the execution of `navigation()` function would stop after the first `if` statement. It is wrong as after that more `if` statements are there instead of `elif`.

**So use `elif` instead of more `if` statements**

```
if navigation_eingabe == 1:
    met1()
elif navigation_eingabe == 2:
    pass
elif navigation_eingabe == 3:
    pass
elif navigation_eingabe == 4:
    pass
elif navigation_eingabe == 5:
    pass
elif navigation_eingabe == 6:
    pass
else:
    print("Pls give only Integer numbers")
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using consecutive `if` statements as opposed to `elif` statements, the Python interpreter treats each block as a separate decisional, so `navigation()` is first evaluating whether `navigation_eingabe == 1`. For an entry of `1` at the input prompt, this is true. Then, because the next line is treated as a separate decisional statement, it checks if `navigation_eingabe == 2`, and so on, until it reaches the following block:

```
if navigation_eingabe == 6:
    pass
else:
    print("Pls give only Integer numbers")
```

At which the interpreter enters the decisional with the comparison `navigation_eingabe == 6`, and evaluates this regardless of whether any of the previous five comparisons were `True` or `False`. This comparison evaluates to `False` because `navigation_eingabe == 1`, and we fall into the `else` block as a catch-all.

Additionally, the `else` clause will never be reached for non-integer input anyway because `int(input())` will raise a `ValueError` exception for anything that cannot be cast as an `int`. To catch non-integer input, you should separate the contents of `navigation()` into a `try` and an `except` block.

I suspect what you are actually trying to do is the following:

```
def navigation():

    try:

        navigation_eingabe = int(input())

        if navigation_eingabe == 1:
            met1()
        elif navigation_eingabe == 2:
            pass
        elif navigation_eingabe == 3:
            pass
        elif navigation_eingabe == 4:
            pass
        elif navigation_eingabe == 5:
            pass
        elif navigation_eingabe == 6:
            pass

    except ValueError:

        print("Please only enter integers.")

def met1():

    print("method1")
    met2()

def met2():

    print("method2")

navigation()
```

For which, when you enter `1` at the prompt, the output is the following:

```
1
method1
method2
```